# Update Err in recently installed ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, updates

Screenshot of update log from newly install Ubuntu server 16.04:

[image]

Comment: Saucy is Ubuntu 13.10 - you mention you got 16.04. This means you should most likely cleanup your sources.list

Comment: Please add the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Dufte, now I've updated the sources.list and it works fine. I able to update most of it but some are still not able.

Guys thanks for your prompt answers. I managed to fixed the issue by my own.